# import a file that's delimited by special characters into an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ascii

I have a file that's delimited by a special character (ctl-A, which has an ASCII code of 1, 0x01 in hex) that I'd like to import into an R dataframe. In `vi` it looks like this:

[image: control+A delimited file]

How do I import this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That character can be used in `sep=`

```
> Lines <- "abc\1def\nABC\1DEF"
> read.table(text = Lines, sep = "\1")
   V1  V2
1 abc def
2 ABC DEF
```

Comment: For some reason, `\1` didn't work as a separator for my file. I put some sample data on https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/dc1008d779b904743c37 . It's probably not cut & pasteable from the browser due to the special characters.

Comment: I downloaded the file using the Download button in github, unpacked it and then `read.table("control_a_data_sample", sep = "\1")` separated it into two fields for me.

Comment: Thanks @GGrothendieck. That works perfectly on the sample data. There must be something peculiar with the file that contains all the records.